# word problem for the fundamental group of complements

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, braid-groups

It is well known that the finite type (pure) Artin groups have solvable word problem. This was proved by Deligne in 1972. His aim was to show that the complement of a simplicial hyperplane arrangement is aspherical. Later in 1992 Ruth Charney proved that these groups are in fact bi-automatic.

My question is the following: 
Are there any other classes of hyperplane arrangements for which it is known that the fundamental group of the complement has solvable word problem ?

In general, let $X$ be a finite-dimensional complex manifold and $D$ be a divisor (preferably having hyperplane-like singularities, need not be a normal crossing divisor). 
What are examples of $X$ and $D$ such that $\pi_1(X\setminus D)$ has a solvable word problem ?

Comment: By hyperplane-like singularities, you probably mean a normal crossing divisor. Anyway, your problem is transcendentaly difficult. (As if you are asking, under what conditions, a group has a solvable word problem.) Even if you take $D=\varnothing$, the problem is hopeless.

Answer (score 2):

Taubes proved that every finitely presented group is the fundamental group of a compact complex 3-manifold. Thus, even if $D$ is empty, anything is possible. On the other hand all known smooth complex quasi projective varieties have fundamental groups with solvable word problem. Thus, if you take your favorite manifold of this type, you get an example you are asking for. For instance, trivial , abelian, nilpotent, hyperbolic, residually finite... groups all have solvable WP. 
There will be smooth projective varieties with such fundamental groups.